# Opening a Python file from another application without saving the file first (Opening a Pandas table from Excel)

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with pandas, and I've just modified a table

Now, I would like to **see my table in excel**, but it's just a quick look, and I will have to modify the table again later on, so I don't want to save my table anywhere.

In other words, the solution

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame()
item_path = "my/path"
my_df.to_csv("my/path")
os.startfile(os.normpath(item_path))
```

Is not what I want. I would like to obtain the same behavior without saving the Dataframe as CSV first.

```
#Something like:
my_df = pd.DataFrame()
start_excel(table_to_load = my_df) #Opens excel with a COPY of my_df
```

### Note

To quickly explore a DataFrame, df.head() is the way, but I want to open my DataFrame from a Tkinter application. I need to use an external program to open this temporary table

Answer (score 0):

you can have a quick look using 
`<dataframe_name>.head()`
it will display top 5 rows by default

or

you can simply write how many rows you want 
`<dataframe_name>.head(<rows_you_want>)`

Comment: Thanks Moksh, but that is not what I am searching for. I've added a brief explanation, to make clear why I asked for such an unusual solution